How to formulate a binomial regression model for the dose-response relationship in Piegorsch, Weinberg and Margolin (1988)?
I am trying to apply logistic regression modelling to binomial proportions data.  Specifically, I am working with the $Biometrics$ paper "Exploring Simple Independent Action in Multifactor Tables of Proportions" by Piegorsch, Weinberg and Margolin (1988).
Here is the data from the paper, on the number of cells that have differentiated upon exposure to two agents TNF and IFN.  200 cells are exposed in each of the 16 combinations of the two agents.

I am trying to model the distribution of the response in terms of exposure to TNF and IFN.
In the paper, I see that the authors have modelled the explanatory variables TNF and IFN as factors, each containing 4 levels.
However, I am trying to use continuous explanatory variables based on TNF and IFN doses.  I have tried transforming the explanatory variables using the square root, log and sin functions, and I tried the logit and cloglog links.
The residual plots do not seem to suggest an adequate model fit.
Among others, the models I tried are as follows:
$$
\log\left( \frac{\pi_i}{1 - \pi_i} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{TNF}_i + \beta_2 \text{IFN}_i + \beta_3 \log(\text{TNF}_i + 1) + \beta_4 \log(\text{IFN}_i + 1)
$$
The plot of my deviance residuals for this looks like this:

Using the cloglog link, I have:
$$
\log\left( -\log(1 - \pi_i) \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{TNF}_i + \beta_2 \text{IFN}_i + \beta_3 \log(\text{TNF}_i + 1) + \beta_4 \log(\text{IFN}_i + 1)
$$
Here are my deviance residuals for the cloglog link:

Instead of the log transformations, I also tried square roots of TNF and IFN, and sin of TNF and IFN.
Is there anything I am missing here?  Or things I could do differently?  I would be grateful for any suggestions or advice you could share about modelling the dose response relationship here.  Thanks so much!

You should assess the fit with the DHARMa package. This doesn't look too bad: fit1 <- glm(cbind(suc, fail) ~ log(IFN + 0.1) * log(TNF + 0.1), data = DT, family = binomial(link = "log")); library(DHARMa); sim <- simulateResiduals(fit1, n = 5e3); plot(sim).

Why do you think you are missing something? Are you referring to a specific problem?

@SextusEmpiricus Thank you so much for your reply!  I think something is missing because of the pattern that I see in the deviance residual plots.  Ideally a model that fits the data well has residuals randomly scattered around 0.  However, here the pattern in the residual plot remains, despite transforming the explanatory variables and using alternative link functions.  This means my models do not fit the data well. :(

Further, my residuals are clustered below ~$0.4$, and are not spread out evenly/randomly over the entire range of fitted values between $(0, 1)$.

The use of a log odds link function seems fine and there is no clear interaction effect for that scale. See the below image where the curves of the log odds versus dose have more or less similar shapes for different values of the other variable.
(The interferon concentration 10 U/ml below is incorrect, should be 20 U/ml, but I lost my code which I don't want to retype, the idea is clear enough)

So the effect sizes based on factors give a good idea of effect size as function of dose.

You could transform the horizontal axis in all kinds of ways that you want to make those relationships linear. But, with only four values a parametric model is too much. A lot of different transformations may create a reasonable straight line. See also: Why would you perform transformations over polynomial regression?

These visualizations are very informative, and instructive as well! Thank you so much for your explanation here. Also thanks a lot for your time. Could I ask one follow-up question please?

In the first $2$ plots, we have the curves of the log odds versus dose for each of the $4$ values of the other variable.  The $y-$axis plots $\log\left( \frac{\pi_i}{1 - \pi_i} \right)$, with the $\pi_i$$s$ being the fitted values from the model output. And the fitted model is: $ \log\left( \frac{\pi_i}{1 - \pi_i} \right) = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \text{TNF}_i + \beta_2 \text{IFN}_i + \beta_3 \log(\text{TNF}_i + 1) + \beta_4 \log(\text{IFN}_i + 1) $  Is my understanding correct here?

@MilanKiRuth12 the effect sizes as function of the TNF and IFN were plotted using the model factors. It gives seven parameters. $$\log\left( \frac{\pi_i}{1 - \pi_i} \right) = f(\text{TNF}_i,\text{IFN}i) = \beta_0 + \begin{bmatrix}\beta_2 & \beta_3 & \beta_4 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{I}{\text{IFN}i = 1} \ \textbf{I}{\text{IFN}i = 20} \ \textbf{I}{\text{IFN}i = 100} \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix}\beta_5 & \beta_6 & \beta_7 \end{bmatrix} \cdot \begin{bmatrix}\textbf{I}{\text{TNF}i = 1} \ \textbf{I}{\text{TNF}i = 20} \ \textbf{I}{\text{TNF}_i = 100} \end{bmatrix}$$

The two final plots for the effect sizes show the function values $f(x,0)$ and $f(0,x)$ on the vertical axes versus x on the horizontal axes.
